# My sprite masks in unity 2d are not working properly

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Iam new to unity and today i tried to work with sprite mask in 2D and it doesnt work. I want the blood stain when the enemy dies to be only on the platform but when i set the blood stains Mask Interaction to "Visible Inside Mask" and i also set the platform sprite mask. But you cant see the blood stain anywhere.

I tried everything in my 1 month programmer power

no code is needed i just need to find out why my sprite masks are not working

I need my blood stain to only be visible on the platform.

Comment: Have you added a sprite to your sprite mask via the inspector?

Comment: Have you watched this video¿
  https://youtu.be/4pl8DcsCQ_k

Comment: Can you include a screenshot of your inspector for the respective gameobjects? (And the hierarchy of the project)